# Como usar align em css para tabelas

Tags: html, css

Galera como monto esta tabela em css?

```
<table border="0" align="right">
```

Quero saber como alinhar uma tabela a direita usando css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente:

```
 table {
     float: right;
 }
```

Comment: Obrigado bem simples

Answer (score 0):

Tente utilizar isso:

```
table {
    /*margin-right: 10%; /* distância até chegar em 100% (baseando-se no lado direito) */
    margin-left: 100% !important;/* distância até chegar em 100% (baseando-se no lado esquerdo) */
}
```

JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/pxL6u3ay/

Comment: não deu certo. com o align="right" a tabela fica encostada no cando direito do monitor, como eu preciso. e com seu css ela fica quase no meu da tela

Comment: Editei minha resposta colocando exemplo

Comment: continua errado amigo, quero que a tabela fique grudada no canto direito. e ela não esta ficando.

Comment: Não funciona nem alterando a margin-left para 100%?

Comment: Se não funcionar, teste colocar um !important, pois outro arquivo css deve estar sobrepondo esse.

Comment: @HugoBorges não está errado, apenas não se adéqua a sua utilização ;)

Comment: de uma olhada nesse exemplo. https://jsfiddle.net/pxL6u3ay/1/ quero que ela fica grudada no lado direito, mas sem usar o align="right" quero fazer isso em css.

Comment: Apenas alterei o margin-left para 100% e funcionou perfeitamente: https://jsfiddle.net/pxL6u3ay/2/

Comment: @HugoBorges -> https://jsfiddle.net/pxL6u3ay/3/

Comment: O exemplo do @VictorGomes utilizando a propriedade right também funciona

Answer (score 0):

acredito que o problema é que a sua pagina possui margem ou padding que não permitem a sua tabela "colar" na direita, tente a solução abaixo e adapte ao restante do seu código para que toda a sua página não quebre:

```
<table border="1" align="right">
```

CSS:

```
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tanta fazer da seguintes formas abaixo, utilizando `float: right;` caso você queira colocar sua tabela à direita, e caso você queira alinhar seu texto à direita dentro da tabela, use `text-align: right;`.

```css
table.table-1 {
  width: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

table.table-2 {
  width: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: right;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<table class="table-1">
  <tr>
    <td>Tabela 1</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="table-2">
  <tr>
    <td>Tabela 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```